# AWS_IO_TLS_ERROR_WRITE_FAILURE when connecting to IoT Core with Cognito Authenticated User

Tags: http, openssl, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam, aws-iot

and thank you.

I have an authenticated user in Cognito User Pools, plus that user pool is connected to an identity pool. I have a python client that is authenticating the user successfully (i get back credentials), but when I connect to IoTt Core and check the result of the connect_future, I get the above error. When I use the same connection logic with certificates, it works properly and I can publish messages. I have turned trace logging on, but still can't find anything more definitive.

I get this connection:

```
[http-connection] - id=0x14e99d8a0: HTTP/1.1 client connection established.
[DEBUG] [2024-01-12T00:59:46Z] 
[000000016b9ff000] [http-stream] - id=0x14e99ecb0: Created client request on connection=0x14e99d8a0
HTTP connection established, sending websocket upgrade request.
Setup success, created websocket=0x14e1a8a00
[DEBUG] [2024-01-12T00:59:46Z] [000000016b9ff000] [websocket] - id=0x14e1a8a00: Websocket client connection established.

The error ultimately is: AWS_IO_TLS_ERROR_WRITE_FAILURE, but there are other errors prior, such as SSLWrite failed with OSStatus error code -9805 and SSLRead failed with OSStatus error code -9805. The final error is: 
[ERROR] [2024-01-12T01:19:00Z] [000000016f26b000] [http-connection] - id=0x107f1adc0: Destroying write message without passing it along, error 1031 (AWS_IO_TLS_ERROR_WRITE_FAILURE)
ERROR:root:Connection failed. error: OnConnectionFailureData(error=AwsCrtError(name='AWS_ERROR_MQTT_UNEXPECTED_HANGUP', message='The connection was closed unexpectedly.', code=5134))
```

This is my code:

```
`def get_user_sub(client) :
    response = client.get_user(
        AccessToken = accesstoken
    )

    attr_sub = None
    for attr in response['UserAttributes']:
        if attr['Name'] == 'sub':
            return attr['Value']
      

# User Pool Client, initiate auth
client = boto3.client('cognito-idp', region_name='us-east-1')

response = client.initiate_auth(
    ClientId=os.getenv('COGNITO_APP_CLIENT_ID'),
    AuthFlow='USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',
    AuthParameters={
        'USERNAME' : os.getenv('COGNITO_USERNAME'),
        'PASSWORD' : os.getenv('COGNITO_PASSWORD')
    }
)

accesstoken = response['AuthenticationResult']['AccessToken']
refreshtoken = response['AuthenticationResult']['RefreshToken']
idtoken = response['AuthenticationResult']['IdToken']

# Now get the internal User ID
attr_sub = get_user_sub(client)


# Connect to cognito-identity
id_client = boto3.client('cognito-identity')
id_response = id_client.get_id(
    AccountId=os.getenv('AWS_ACCOUNT_ID'), # AWS Account ID - I don't like this.
    IdentityPoolId=os.getenv('COGNITO_IDENTITY_POOL_ID'), # Make Env, and can this be queried?
    Logins={
        os.getenv('COGNITO_USER_POOL_URL'): idtoken # This is OK
    }
)

# Used in connection - users cognito identity ID.
identityId = id_response['IdentityId']

creds_response = id_client.get_credentials_for_identity(
    IdentityId=identityId,
    Logins={
        os.getenv('COGNITO_USER_POOL_URL'): idtoken
    }
)

# Now start connecting to IoT Core


# Create the cognito credentials provider
cognito_id_pool_endpoint = f"cognito-identity.{os.getenv('COGNITO_REGION')}.amazonaws.com"
l = [(os.getenv('COGNITO_USER_POOL_URL'), idtoken)] # USER POOL

provider = auth.AwsCredentialsProvider.new_cognito(
    endpoint=cognito_id_pool_endpoint,
    identity=identityId,
    logins=l,
    tls_ctx=io.ClientTlsContext(io.TlsContextOptions()))

mqtt_connection = mqtt_connection_builder.websockets_with_default_aws_signing(
    endpoint=os.getenv('IOT_ENDPOINT'),
    region=os.getenv('IOT_REGION'),
    client_id=f'my-device:{uuid.uuid4()}',
    on_connection_failure=on_connection_failure,
    on_connection_interrupted=on_connection_interrupted,
    on_connection_resumed=on_connection_resumed,
    credentials_provider=provider)

connect_future = mqtt_connection.connect()

connect_future.result() -- THIS IS THE LINE THAT FAILS
logging.info('Connected!')`
```